# how to hide column if showColumn state is true

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am rendering a table in react using antd

I am trying to show column if the showColumn state is true and hide the column when it is false

```
const menuColumns = [
    {
        title: "Date",
        dataIndex: "createdAt",
        key: "createdAt",
        render: (_, { createdAt }) => (
            <>
                <Moment format="D MMM, YY">{createdAt}</Moment>
            </>
        ),
    },
    {
        title: "Action",
        dataIndex: "",
        key: "",
        className: showColumn ? "show" : "hide",
        render: record => (
            <>
                {!record.kitchen_received ?
                    <Button type="primary" onClick={() => showModal(record)}>
                        Delivered
                    </Button> : <i className='bi-check-lg'></i>}
            </>
        ),
    },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can potentially just avoid to add the whole column to `menuColumns` if you don't need to add it? So something like this?

```
const menuColumns = [
    {
        title: "Date",
        dataIndex: "createdAt",
        key: "createdAt",
        render: (_, { createdAt }) => (
            <>
                <Moment format="D MMM, YY">{createdAt}</Moment>
            </>
        ),
    },
    (showColumn ? {
        title: "Action",
        dataIndex: "",
        key: "",
        render: record => (
            <>
                {!record.kitchen_received ?
                    <Button type="primary" onClick={() => showModal(record)}>
                        Delivered
                    </Button> : <i className='bi-check-lg'></i>}
            </>
        ),
    } : {})
];
```

Or based on the way you set it up with `classNames` you can just display none when the column has the `hide` class applied?

Comment: ```...( showColumn? {``` Should ```be ( showColumn? {```

Answer (score 0):

The solution @leo gave would also work. Alternatively, you can keep the column in state and update the state by pushing the required column on click, dynamically.
This method can help you push columns with dynamic properties which you can pass onClick.
For ex: The user has the option to select a different number of fruits and you want to show the fruit name as the column.

To hide them: You can simply delete them from the state.